# module pass custom url parameters

Tags: magento-1.9, module, url

i want to show custom url parameter in page created via module

what is did i created a module to show page with custom page

issue is how to pass and show parameter in url like product id  of parent product

With my module i am able to open url with dummy content: like below

```
abc.com/related
```

i want to pass and show parameters like

```
abc.com/releted/productid/11
```

Below is code of my module **MY_Related**

1: app\code\local\MY\Related\Block\Index.php

```
<?php   
class MY_Related_Block_Index extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{   

}
```

2: app\code\local\MY\Related\controllers\IndexController.php

```
<?php
class MY_Related_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function IndexAction() {

      $this->loadLayout();   
      $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__("Titlename"));
            $breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock("breadcrumbs");
      $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("home", array(
                "label" => $this->__("Home Page"),
                "title" => $this->__("Home Page"),
                "link"  => Mage::getBaseUrl()
           ));

      $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("titlename", array(
                "label" => $this->__("Titlename"),
                "title" => $this->__("Titlename")
           ));

      $this->renderLayout(); 

    }
}
```

3: app\code\local\MY\Related\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MY_Related>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </MY_Related>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <related>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>MY_Related</module>
            <frontName>related</frontName>
          </args>
      </related>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <related>
              <file>related.xml</file>
            </related>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <related>
        <class>MY_Related_Helper</class>
      </related>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <related>
        <class>MY_Related_Block</class>
      </related>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

4: app\code\local\MY\Related\Helper\Data.php

```
<?php
class MY_Related_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `related/index/index/product/11`. Then you should be able to read the `product` param like this:

```
$product = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('product');
```

Comment: what to do if i do not need double index/index

Comment: then you need to create a custom router. take a look at this and try to adapt the answer to your needs.

Comment: can you help how can it be fixed using router

Answer (score 1):

To get all the parameters from the url `related/index/index/product/11/id/4` 
then you can use this:

```
$product = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
```